# Export a function with Node JS

Tags: node.js

I need help with function export in Node.Js

Here is my **module.js**

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client : 'mysql',
    connection : {
        host : 'localhost',
        user : 'root',
        password : '123',
        database : 'dbNode'
    }
}),bookshelf = require('bookshelf')(knex);

var user = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName : 'tblUsers',
   idAttribute : 'email'
});

var note = bookshelf.Model.extend({
   tableName : 'tblNotes',
   idAttribute : 'noteId'
});


module.exports = {
   User : user,
   Note : note,

};

module.exports = function(owner) {
  return knex('note').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId');
}
```

I have to export both the function and the bookshelf models (User and Note) but when I try to use the Model.User it returns me the error: *Model.User is not a function*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's look at your code:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
};

module.exports = function(owner) {
    ...
}
```

You're assigning two different things to the same property. The second assignment overrides the first one.

---

To do what you're asking, you need to export the function first and then add the properties separately:

```
module.exports = function(owner) {
    ...
}

module.exports.User = user;
module.exports.Note = note;
```

This is standard in node.

Better yet, don’t assign the function directly to `module.exports` but add it as a property to it:

```
module.exports.myFunction = function(owner) {
    ...
}

module.exports.User = user;
module.exports.Note = note;
```

This way you have real separate exports instead of an exported function that *strangely* also has User and Note properties.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining `note` and `user` with `var`, use `exports.note` and `exports.user`

```
 exports.user = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'tblUsers',
    idAttribute : 'email'
 });

 exports.note = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'tblNotes',
    idAttribute : 'noteId'
 });
```

Then you'll more likely than not have to set your function export to a named function. (or make it a class?)

```
 exports.MyClass = function(owner) {
   return knex('note').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId');
 }
```

If you're worried about ease of imports, you can assign `MyClass` to a variable, instead of the whole package

```
 var MyClass=require('module').MyClass;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you put into "module.exports" is exported.

If you use it several time, the last one overides everything else. In your case, you put a function into it, which overriders object with User and Note which was there before.

In your case, this can be the solution

```
module.exports = {
   User : user,
   Note : note,
   returnNoteByOwner(owner) {
      knex('note').where('public',1).orWhere({ownerName : owner}).select('noteId');
   }
};
```

---

Then you can access it as following

```
var module = require('module');
console.log(module.User);
console.log(module.Note);
console.log(module.returnNoteByOwner('hisName'));
```