# How to export function?

Tags: javascript, node-modules

I'm trying to export this function to another file. But It doesn't work properly. Just want to make sure am I doing everything right?

```
  window.colorAddElement = addedElements => {
    const addedElementsDOMNode = document.getElementById(
      `color-added-elements-"${num}"`,
    )

    if (colorAddNewClicked) {
      text = " "
      colorAddNewClicked = false
    }
    text += " " + addedElements
    addedElementsDOMNode.innerHTML = text
  }
```

exporting:

```
module.exports.AddElement =   window.colorAddElement = addedElements => {
    const addedElementsDOMNode = document.getElementById(
      `color-added-elements-"${num}"`,
    )

    if (colorAddNewClicked) {
      text = " "
      colorAddNewClicked = false
    }
    text += " " + addedElements
    addedElementsDOMNode.innerHTML = text
  }
```

Importing :

```
const ColorAddElement = require("./colorSet.js")
```

Calling :

```
ColorAddElement.AddElement(addedElements);
```

Comment: try this `export default function() {}` - documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export  or this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37613507/export-a-function-with-node-js

Comment: Have you tried seperating the assigment to window from the export? `const addElement = ...; window.addElement = addElement; module.exports = addElement;`

Comment: What is not working properly? Has node produced an `Error` we can look at? I feel like it _might_ be that `module.exports` by default wouldnt be an `Object`, you need to assign it an object or function or class or ... Anyhow, I feel like doing `module.exports.whatEverKey` should tell you that you cannot assign that key to a non-object, but I might be wrong.

Comment: There is no `window` object in *Node.js* modules

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `CommomJS` module system you should do the following:

```
ColorAddElement(addedElements);
```

With the export you are only exporting a function in this code section:

```
module.exports.AddElement =   window.colorAddElement = addedElements => {
    const addedElementsDOMNode = document.getElementById(
      `color-added-elements-"${num}"`,
    )

    if (colorAddNewClicked) {
      text = " "
      colorAddNewClicked = false
    }
    text += " " + addedElements
    addedElementsDOMNode.innerHTML = text
  }
```

Therefore the value stored in the variable of the require function is the function which you exported:

```
const ColorAddElement = require("./colorSet.js"); // ColorAddElement is now your exported function
```

Comment: Do I need to use dot after ColorAddElement ? It shows an error 
ColorAddElement.(addedElements);

Comment: Excuse me for that dot. remove the dot, ColorAddElement is a function and for the invocation the dot is not required.